# java array method to return an array

Tags: java

I want to return an array for the below method.

But I can't figure it out how? 
m,n to be included in the array

```
static int[] records(int[] score) {
    int m=0,n=0;
    int max = score[0],min = score[0];

    for(int i=1;i<score.length;i++){
        if(score[i]>max){
            m+=1;
            max = score[i];
        }
        if(score[i]<min){
            n+=1;
            min = score[i]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What Array should contain?

Comment: return statement ?

Comment: dunno... what about 
    `return score` ?
but that's seems a bit pointless

Comment: please read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: What array you would like to return ? What are the values you would like to store in the array?

Comment: m,n should be returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to return an array with two values (namely the `min` and the `max`), you can build that in one line like `return new int[] { min, max };` I would also prefer `Integer.min(int, int)` and `Integer.max(int, int)` for finding those values. Like,

```
static int[] records(int[] score) {
    int max = score[0], min = score[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < score.length; i++) {
        max = Integer.max(max, score[i]);
        min = Integer.min(min, score[i]);
    }
    return new int[] { min, max };
}
```

And if you really need `m` and `n` as well, you can add them back and return them

```
static int[] records(int[] score) {
    int m = 0, n = 0, max = score[0], min = score[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < score.length; i++) {
        if (score[i] > max) {
            m++;
            max = score[i];
        }
        if (score[i] < min) {
            n++;
            min = score[i];
        }
    }
    return new int[] { n, m, min, max };
}
```

Comment: return part of your code has matched to my code

Comment: 2nd code worked